# label not showing text when passing data from Tabbed Page

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin... I have a problem when I want to show a description in a label. I have a listView with different items and when the user clicks in one item the app moves to a Tabbed Page with two main windows one for description and the other one for opinions. Here you have a diagram. [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRnW8.jpg)

I pass the object from the item clicked to the Tabbed Page and from it I pass data to its children. Here is the code

---> Model

```
 public class Item
{
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public Double price;
    public int stock;
    public List<String> opinions;

    public Item(String name, String description ,Double price, int stock, List<String> opinions)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.stock = stock;
        this.opinions = opinions;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.name + " " + this.price + " $" + this.stock + " ud";
    }
    
}
```

---> event handler to navigate to the TabPage once an item from listView is clicked.

```
private async void parent_listView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (Item)e.SelectedItem;
        //await Navigation.PushAsync(new TabPage(new Datos(itemList[e.SelectedItemIndex] ), new Opinions(itemList[e.SelectedItemIndex] )));
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new TabPage(item));
    }
```

----> How I get the data to the TabPage and send to its children.

```
 public partial class TabPage : TabbedPage
{
    Item item;
    public TabPage(Item item)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.item = item;
        inichildren(item);


    }

    private void inichildren(Item item)
    {
        
        Datos d = new Datos(item);
        Opinions o = new Opinions(item);
       
    }

}
```

---> Finally the Datos class where I am interested in.

```
 public Datos()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        
        
    }

    public Datos(Item i)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        
        
        lbl_description.Text = i.description.ToString();
        lbl_item_price.Text = i.price.ToString();
    }
```

Everything works fine and even I added some break point to see if I receive the data in Datos class and all labels variables seems to point to the right data. But the thing is that when I initialize the labels in the constructors no data appears on the screen....
I am new to Xamarin and don't have idea why this is happening. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: is `Datos` one of the child pages you defined in the XAML?  If so, then creating a **new** instance of the page in code is not doing anything useful.  There is already an existing instance created in the XAML that is shown on the page.  As I noted in your earlier question passing data on the constructor will not work with the child pages, because they are automatically created by the TabbedPage.

Comment: Yes, Datos is one of the child pages defined in xaml. I don't know how to solve the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to pass data to the child pages via the constructor, you will need to setup the pages in code, not XAML.

```
private void inichildren(Item item)
{
    Datos d = new Datos(item);
    Opinions o = new Opinions(item);
   
    // since you are adding the child pages here, remove them from the TabbedPage XAML
    this.Children.Add(d);
    this.Children.Add(o);
}
```